# Prove that the given sequence converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

**The given sequence is:**   $ x_n = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!} $

I want to first try showing that it is a cauchy sequence.
The definitions I have for cauchy sequence are
1)$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\, \exists N \in\Bbb{N} \,$  $\ni $ $\forall n,m>N \ $ , it follows that $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$

2)$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\, \exists N \in\Bbb{N} \,$ $\ni $  $\forall n,>N \, p\in \Bbb{N} \ $ , it follows that $|x_m-x_{n+p}|<\epsilon$

Comment: Hint : For sufficiently large $n$ , you have $2^n<n!$ , hence $\frac{1}{2^n}>\frac{1}{n!}$. Now compare the given series to the geometric series with $q=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cauchy Convergence criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694859/cauchy-convergence-criterion)

Comment: $e=e^1=\Sigma_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1^n}{n!}$. Your sequence is the partial sums minus the value at $n=0$ so that sequence should converge to $e-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Monotone Convergence Theorem

$ x_n = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!} $

and

$ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!}+ + \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

It shows $x_n$ is increasing

Since $\frac{1}{n!}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ (it can prove by induction $\forall n \in N$)

$ x_n = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!} \leq  \frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<2$, $n\in N$

It shows $x_n$ is bounded above

By the monotone convergence theorem, $x_n$ both increasing and bounded above then it is convergent.

Comment: How did you get the equation $\frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2}+ ... +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 2- \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ ?

Comment: $S_n=1+q+q^2+\dots + q^{n-1}= \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$, $q\neq 1$ sum of the terms of geometric sequence